# Where can I publish interesting code problems?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I've got interesting problem in CSS, that isn't totally question for StackOverflow, because it has some rules (for example, it's important to solve it only using CSS, but it's not the only way), is it possible to post it somewhere else on StackExchange?

Comment: Is it a quiz you wish to administer, or a practical programming issue you are experiencing and would like to get help on?

Comment: @Won't I think it's closer to quiz

Comment: If you want to administer a coding quiz, [codegolf.se]

Comment: note that usually PPCG challenges are solved with golfing languages. restricting the allowed languages won't win you points there

Comment: imposing limitations like only using CSS doesn't necessarily mean it isn't a question for SO

Comment: @Vogel612'sShadow: I, for one, would certainly upvote a good language specific challenge on PPCG -- where "good" means (among other more or less obvious things like, you know, being interesting) having an actual *reason* for the language restriction, i.e. something other than just "I like language X better than language Y." A challenge to implement some nontrivial functionality on a web page without using any Turing-complete scripting languages like JavaScript could certainly qualify IMO. Do note, however, that all PPCG challenges still need an objective winning criterion (e.g. code length).

Comment: @Won't PPCG is for code competitions, not for quizzes or your homework problems. Please link our help center when referring to us >_>

Comment: @Vogel612'sShadow It's also good to note that PPCG challenges are open to all languages, and people tend to answer in golfing languages. Reading any of the challenges' answers on PPCG would show you that a good deal of people answer in languages like Java, Ruby, Haskell, C++, C, C#, and many other well-known, _non-golfing_ languages.

Comment: @Downgoat oops... I'll get the toilet brush...